# Is there a way to dynamically instantiate a class type

Tags: ios, swift, class, reflection, swift2

I would like to do something on the lines of (pseudo code):

```
let class_name = "MyClass"
let RealClass = class_name()
```

I am familiar with http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/05/instantiating-classes-by-name-in-swift/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use `NSClassFromString` to get class  then cast to the type you want.

For example:

```
var dynamicClass = NSClassFromString("Test") as? Test.Type
    if dynamicClass != nil{
        var instance = dynamicClass!()
        instance.test()
}
```

The class `Test`

```
@objc(Test)
class Test{
   func test() {
       println("dynamic")
    }
    required  init() {

    }
}
```